# Making remote server calls in an Android application

Tags: java, android, thrift

I've made an apache thrift server and I have a service which contains several functions.
I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to make calls to the remote server from my android application.

My problem is that I can't make calls from the MainActivity thread (the main thread) - and I need to use most of the remote functions in my main activity methods.

I tried to make a static class with a static member called "Server" equals to the server object, and I set it in another thread and then I tried to call it in the main thread (the main activity class) - but I had errors because of jumping from one thread to another..

To be more specified I want something like that:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private service.Client myService;
  
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ..
    ... Some stuff that define myService (In a new thread ofcourse) ...
  }

  ...
  
  private void MyFunc1() {
    myService.Method1();
  }

  private void MyFunc2() {
    myService.Method2();
  }

  private void MyFunc3() {
    myService.Method3();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got a library for talking to REST APIs. Feel free to slice, dice, and re-use: https://github.com/nedwidek/Android-Rest-API

The code is BSD or GPL.

Here's how I use what I have (I've trimmed MainActivity a bit, hopefully not too much):

```
package com.hatterassoftware.voterguide.api;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class GoogleCivicApi {
    protected final String baseUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/us_v1/";

    protected String apiKey = "AIzaSyBZIP5uY_fMF35SVVrytpKgHtppBbj8J0I";

    public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";

    protected static HashMap<String, String> headers;

    static {
        headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }

    public String createUrl(String uri, HashMap<String, String> params) {

        String url = baseUrl + uri + "?key=" + apiKey;

        if (params != null) {
            for (String hashKey: params.keySet()) {
                url += hashKey + "=" + params.get(hashKey) + "&";
            }

            url = url.substring(0, url.length());
        }

        return url;
    }
}

package com.hatterassoftware.voterguide.api;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.hatterassoftware.restapi.GetTask;
import com.hatterassoftware.restapi.HttpReturn;
import com.hatterassoftware.restapi.RestCallback;
import com.hatterassoftware.voterguide.api.callbacks.ElectionCallback;
import com.hatterassoftware.voterguide.api.models.Election;

public class ElectionsQuery extends GoogleCivicApi implements RestCallback {

    GetTask getTask;
    ElectionCallback callback;
    final String TAG = "ElectionQuery";

    public ElectionsQuery(ElectionCallback callback) {

        String url = this.createUrl("elections", null);

        this.callback = callback;

        Log.d(TAG, "Creating and executing task for: " + url);
        getTask = new GetTask(url, this, null, null, null);
        getTask.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostSuccess() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostSuccess entered");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskComplete(HttpReturn httpReturn) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onTaskComplete entered");

        Log.d(TAG, "httpReturn.status = " + httpReturn.status);
        if (httpReturn.content != null) Log.d(TAG, httpReturn.content);
        if (httpReturn.restException != null) Log.d(TAG, "Exception in httpReturn", httpReturn.restException);

        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement electionArrayJson = ((JsonObject)parser.parse(httpReturn.content)).get("elections");

        Log.d(TAG, electionArrayJson.toString());

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(GoogleCivicApi.DATE_FORMAT).create();
        Election[] elections = gson.fromJson(electionArrayJson.toString(), Election[].class);

        callback.retrievedElection(elections);
    }

}

package com.hatterassoftware.voterguide;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.hatterassoftware.voterguide.api.ElectionsQuery;
import com.hatterassoftware.voterguide.api.VoterInfoQuery;
import com.hatterassoftware.voterguide.api.callbacks.ElectionCallback;
import com.hatterassoftware.voterguide.api.callbacks.VoterInfoCallback;
import com.hatterassoftware.voterguide.api.models.Election;
import com.hatterassoftware.voterguide.api.models.VoterInfo;

import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements ElectionCallback, VoterInfoCallback {

    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    public Button submit;
    public Spinner state;
    public Spinner election;
    public EditText address;
    public EditText city;
    public EditText zip;

    private int count=0;
    private Object lock = new Object();

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    public static final String VOTER_INFO = "com.hatterassoftware.voterguide.VOTER_INFO";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.home_progressBar);

        Resources res = getResources();

        SharedPreferences mPrefs = getApplicationSharedPreferences();
        ImageButton gpsButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.locate);
        try {
            LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

            if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE)) {
                gpsButton.setClickable(false);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            gpsButton.setClickable(false);
            gpsButton.setEnabled(false);
        }

        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        submit.setClickable(false);
        submit.setEnabled(false);

        state = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.state);
        election = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.election);
        address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.streetAdress);
        city = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.city);
        zip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.zip);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                doSubmit();             
            }           
        });

        gpsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                doLocate();
            }
        });

        // Let's check for network connectivity before we get down to business.
        if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(this, true)) {

            // Show the disclaimer on first run.
            if(mPrefs.getBoolean("firstRun", true)) {
                AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
                alert.setCancelable(false);
                alert.setTitle(res.getString(R.string.welcome));
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);

                TextView alertContents = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.custom_dialog_text);
                alertContents.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                alertContents.setText(Html.fromHtml(res.getString(R.string.welcome_dialog_text)));
                alert.setView(alertContents);
                alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        SharedPreferences mPrefs = getApplicationSharedPreferences();
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putBoolean("firstRun", false);
                        editor.commit();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        retrieveElections();
                    }
                });
                alert.show();
            } else {
                retrieveElections();
            }
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Let's check for network connectivity before we get down to business.
        Utils.isNetworkAvailable(this, true);

        LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
        if (!(manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) 
                || manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is not available", 2).show();
            ImageButton gpsButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.locate);
            gpsButton.setClickable(false);
        }
    }

    public SharedPreferences getApplicationSharedPreferences() {
        Context mContext = this.getApplicationContext();
        return mContext.getSharedPreferences("com.hatterassoftware.voterguide", MODE_PRIVATE);      
    }

    private void showSpinner() {
        synchronized(lock) {
            count++;
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private void hideSpinner() {
        synchronized(lock) {
            count--;
            if(count < 0) {  // Somehow we're trying to hide it more times than we've shown it.
                count=0;
            }
            if (count == 0) {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }

    public void retrieveElections() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Retrieving the elections");

        showSpinner();

        ElectionsQuery query = new ElectionsQuery(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void retrievedElection(Election... elections) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Retrieved the elections");

        hideSpinner();

        for (int i=0; i<elections.length; i++) {
            Log.d(TAG, elections[i].toString());
        }

        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, elections);
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.election);
        spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: thank for your help - but i'm sorry i can't understand anything from this code.. can you try to explain me the steps of that code?

Comment: Yes, it is a little specific to doing RESTful calls. The basic points are that you cannot do the network call on the UI thread. You need to do it in an AsyncTask. So you need to create your own class that extends AsyncTask (use GetTask as an example). Then you also need to be able to catch the data when it is ready. So you create a callback interface (like RestCallback). So GetTask.execute() starts the call doInBackground() is the work to do on the new thread. onPostExecute() is run when the work is gone. This will call the Callback method.

Comment: Your activity implements your callback interface and catches the data.